# performance tuning: for each vs forall

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following pl/sql procedure:

```
create or replace procedure processData (a_date Date, r_offset Number, r_limit Number) as
begin
for r in (select * from (select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from (select* from TABLE1 T1 where T1.date=a_date) a 
 where rownum <= r_limit) where rnum >= r_offset) loop

 if (/*some condition on column values */) then
   /* insert into A*/
 else 
   /*insert into B*/
 end if; 

end loop;
end;
```

as you can see it is made with for each.

I was now wondering about doing that with for-all statement: this would involve gathering data inside of table variables and then, after populating those variables, perform 2 forall statements: one for table A and one for table B.

Would this greatly improve my program's performances?

edit:
I just noticed that this program is, in general, very very slow! I tried processing 10k records and it almost took 30secs! Where could the general problem be?

Comment: Have you tried it? It seems that you should be able to answer this question yourself.

Comment: I am new to pl/sql and this script was given to me, so before digging in I would like to know if it is worth a try... (actual program is more complicated than this example, there is a lot of if branches and so on)

Comment: Would this not depend on Table T1, the size, columns, indexes, statistics?

Comment: WIll it improve performance?  Probably?  How much?  It depends on your code, your Oracle version, etc.  You're in a much better position to test it.  Your `select` statement, though, is missing an `order by` in the inner subquery so it is not guaranteed to return a stable set of results.  The fact that you have a pagination query in a procedure is also suspicious because it strongly implies that you have some other code that is calling this procedure in a loop.

Comment: Yes it is called by tasks in my main program...thanks for the order by tip, the only indexed field I can put this clausole on has a lot of identical values (it is a date field), would it be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just don't use plain SQL - `conditional insert`:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm

I bet that it will be at least 100 times faster than any PL/SQL loop, even FORALL.

```
INSERT FIRST
WHEN /*some condition on column values */
    THEN INTO /* insert into A */
ELSE INTO /*insert into B*/
select * from (select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from (select* from TABLE1 T1 where T1.date=a_date) a 
 where rownum <= r_limit) where rnum >= r_offset
```

Simple demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2019/1

Comment: ...I love you man, I have no other words! 1sec to process about 170k rows! That's just great!